# Are there generally any privacy issues with giving out a journalctl output?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd-journald, privacy

As the title states, I'm just wondering if pasting the logs from systemd might have any personally sensitive information, as I know commands like `inxi` can with internet information. 
I was under no impression that systemd had anything sensitive, but I'm doing some troubleshooting and am seeing mac addresses from my firewall and things that could possibly look "suspicious" -- or are just a hash for something at that moment, I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

(Using Arch Linux.)

Comment: MAC addresses usually do uniquely identify you but you can filter them out or replace using sed/regexp. At the same time I don't know a single Linux application which sends your MAC addresses to the Internet, so I'm not sure how the said addresses can be used against you. Aside from MAC addresses, there could be various UID, e.g. your root device ID: `root=UUID=`, your timezone info, partition table and various other pieces of quite unique info.

Comment: inxi of course has the -z / --filter flag to filter out anything that might be construed as not to be shared in public. Most things that people consider sensitive aren't, but MAC addresses and IP addresses certainly are, but systemd journalctl isn't really about gathering complete sys info, so it's sensitive data would be I expect much more limited in scope than what inxi can expose if -z is not used. Most other data is really only of theoretical interest I think, home directory names [user names], hostname, these were over time added to inxi filters just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Lizardx the threat we want to protect against is tracking, e.g. tracing an activity of a person across the internet. For example I had to give the MAC of my PC to my employer (because he bought the PC), so if I post the MAC on the internet he can track my activity, get the username I have on that forum, and so the other activities I carried in that forum, and if I use the same username in other forums (which I don't), my activity on them as well.

Comment: Thus the -z filter feature.